# Does rvm install 1.9.3 install with OpenSSL support by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

If I do `rvm install 1.9.3` will it install with OpenSSL support? Isn't OpenSSL required for Rails when you do `bundle install`? In the Gemfile you have `source 'https://rubygems.org'`.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled everything (rvm, rails, ruby, etc) on my macbook.

Installed homebrew

Installed rvm

Ran `rvm requirements run force`

Ran `rvm install rails`

`rails new sample_app`

`cd sample_app`

*Note:* `source 'https://rubygems.org'` is present in Gemfile, openssl is required!

`bundle install` **and it worked**!

**No need to specify:** `--with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`